Questions Related to GNSS with ATtiny ICs
A while back I was given a few ATtiny 804s.  I've been looking to build a small GNSS device as I wanted to get some raw GPX data without using a phone. I thought I might be able to use the ATtiny 804s for that. I'm fairly new to electrical and PCB design and couldn't find anyone trying this without an Arduino.
I've put together the diagram below (apologies on the mess I haven't tidied it up yet) having settled on the Quectel L80-R GNSS module. I've also added the ability to store the data on an SD card and read the data and charge a lithium ion cell via USB.

Will the USB system work in the configuration I've chosen, especially if using USB-C? The FT220X seemed like it should work as a USB interface.
Can I do what I have done on pin 7 of the ATtiny and pin 3 of the USB charger to monitor if the USB is plugged in?
I've seen different sources say that the SPI needs a pull-up resistor especially when using an SD card.  Is a pull-up required?
Does anyone have any other suggestions to improve this design?



Please ask the actual question in the title.
